# Ios how to recognize a simple Logo on a white background?

Tags: ios, opencv, image-recognition

I'm trying to write an app that recognize a logo saved in app bundle and readed as UIImage. I have did a search before make this question, the only free solution seems to be OpenCv. I have tried it in a demo i had download from [toptal_logo_detector](https://github.com/altaibayar/toptal_logo_detector) . The demo works and i can find my logo everywhere i place it. Anyway the camera is very slow, too slow to use it in a real app. Maybe there's a way to optimize it, but my question is another. 
I have to recognize a vector logo (always the same logo)  centered in a white background ,something like this wifi logo:
[image]

My only solution is the complex OpenCV? There's a free and simpler way to achive the result: YES here there's your logo/No there isn't ?

Answer (score 0):

I found [this tutorial](http://toptal.com/machine-learning/real-time-object-detection-using-mser-in-ios) (with project download) that does what you want using OpenCV